# Parse Cloud Code: Modify Object before Retrieval

Tags: parse-platform

Let's say I have a Users class and a Posts class, and each Post object has a User pointer. I also have a Comment class, and each Comment has a User pointer. Whenever I fetch a User, I want to fetch all the Posts and Comments that user has made in one network query. Compounding sub-queries won't work, since I have multiple data types. Ideally, I would like to have the Posts and Comments be properties of the retrieved User object.

Is there a way, in Cloud Code, to intercept object requests and modify them to have the appropriate properties before sending to the client?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't modify an object on retrieval, but you can write your own Cloud Function. In your Cloud Function you could take the ID of a user as a parameter, then create a composite object by combining the output of your 3 queries into one result.

You'll need to query:

- User object
- Posts for that user
- Comments for that user

You could get the promise for each of those queries (`find()` etc return a promise object) and use `Parse.Promise.when(userQueryPromise, postQueryPromise commentQueryPromise)` to build your composite object and return it.

```
var _ = require('underscore');

Parse.Cloud.define('getUserWithPostsAndComments', function(request, response) {
    var userId = request.params.userId;

    var userPointer = new Parse.User();
    userPointer.id = userId;

    var userQuery = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);

    var postQuery = new Parse.Query('Post');
    postQuery.equalTo('user', userPointer);

    var commentQuery = new Parse.Query('Comment');
    commentQuery.equalTo('user', userPointer);

    Parse.Promise.when(userQuery.get(userId), postQuery.find(), commentQuery.find())
    .then(function(user, posts, comments) {
        var composite = {
            // User properties you want
            name: user.get('username'),
            email: user.get('email')
        };
        // Post properties you want
        composite.posts = _.map(posts, function(post) {
            return {
                id: post.id,
                title: post.get('title')
            };
        });
        // Comment properties you want
        composite.comments = _.map(comments, function(comment) {
            return {
                id: comment.id,
                body: comment.get('bodyText')
            };
        });
        // return the composite object
        response.success(composite);
    }, function(error) {
        response.error(error);
    });
});
```

Alternatively the above then block could just return the raw results, e.g.:

```
.then(function(user, posts, comments) {
    return {
        user: user,
        posts: posts,
        comments: comments
    };
}, function(error) {
    // etc...
```

Comment: Although I want these additional fields to be retrieved in every user query I make, using cloud functions I basically have to list every possible query I could ever need and do this logic over and over again. Not ideal, but I suppose it works.

Comment: Is there a .when() analogue in iOS? I know there is an orQuery, but it only supports multiple queries that all return the same class

Comment: @sddhhanover There's an Objective-C Promise implementation (RXPromise) detailed here: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/184597/success-failure-blocks-vs-completion-block/219929#219929

Comment: Thanks a lot, although I had nothing to do with this problem but I used small part of your code (where you define `var composite = {}`) to resolve mine..thanks again dude